# g++ -xc option not working?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

```
$ cat | g++ -xc -
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
<stdin>:1: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

$ g++ --v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-2ubuntu1'
--with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
--prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id
--with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext
--enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib
--enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug
--enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic 
--enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu 
--target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-2ubuntu1)
```

A similar C program works with gcc. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Nilesh.

Comment: `-xc` looks to be working as designed, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: -xc++ works, I misunderstood what -xc stands for, hence the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is not C++.  The header `<iostream>` is a C++ header.  If you want to compile C++, then you need to use the `-xc++` option, not `-xc`.